# How to implement this signature?

Tags: java, fingerprint

I have this fingerprint for string s, 
**f(s) = (S[1]r^m-1) xor (S[2]r^m-2) xor....(xor S[n]r^0)) mod (2^32)**
let s contains only a's and b's (0,1 respectively).

If it were addition instead of xor then it would be easy. We can solve it using the rule:
(a + b)mod m = ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m, but here it's not the case.
So, any idea keep in mind that I cannot compute e.g. r^m-1 since I may face integer overflow.

Comment: It looks like this question might be better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: define integer overflow.  Do you actually mean Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: yes, if r^m-1 is too large then it will truncated.

Comment: What are r and m? Can you point us to the document that defines this signature algorithm?

Comment: Are you sure that modulo isn't associative over xor the way it is for addition?

Comment: m is the length of s, r is large integer value

Comment: no it is not associative. i checked it

Answer (score 2):

If the concern is overflow, I recommend using `BigInteger` this will not overflow assuming you have enough memory:

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)  :

> Semantics of arithmetic operations exactly mimic those of Java's
>   integer arithmetic operators, as defined in The Java Language
>   Specification. For example, division by zero throws an
>   ArithmeticException, and division of a negative by a positive yields a
>   negative (or zero) remainder. All of the details in the Spec
>   concerning overflow are ignored, as BigIntegers are made as large as
>   necessary to accommodate the results of an operation.

[SO explaning overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163721/205426)

> BigInteger is not really a type. It's a class. It's a wrapper class
>   designed to give you the same functionality as an int, but allows you
>   to use numbers as big as you need without the worry of overflow.
>
> Types do overflow because they are simply a couple of bytes (exact
>   amount depends on the type) of memory, and once that small amount of
>   memory overflows, so do the numbers.
>
> No class "overflows" unless it is specifically designed to do so (or
>   if you run out of resources). A class is defined with enough memory
>   for everything it contains, which would mostly be references to other
>   classes or other data structures.

Comment: I have already tried that, but if you noticed that my modulo is 2^32 and BigIntger.pow(int). 2^32 wont fit in int variable.

Comment: @ajab BigInteger is **NOT** the same as an int.  I have used BigInteger to calculate numbers far **greater** than `2^32`

Comment: yes, it could work but still I am not looking for such answer.
what i need is a way to manipulate the structure of the signature to deal with it using long or even int variables.
the problem is the modulo is not associative over xor!

Comment: I'm pretty well convinced that overflow is not an issue here, and the entire thing can be done in 32-bit integer math.

Answer (score 1):

Overflow is not a problem, because:

- XOR is a bitwuse operation (the presence/absence of higher bits does affect the result)
- the final action of `mod 2^32` masks off higher bits

Just use a `long` to hold your result (64 bits, so bit 31 does not cause sign issues).

Comment: i will have overflow before doing any xoring for example:
let r = 6548745, m-1 = 17
then 6548745 ^ 17 wont fit even long variable!

Comment: If you compute it on a 32-bit machine, the overflow will be harmless, and you'll be effectively computing the modulo 2^32 operation for free

Answer (score 0):

The Java `BigInteger` class does not support raising to exponents of type `BigInteger`. What you can do is implement an algorithm to compute the power yourself, using [Exponentiation by Squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). These usually come in the form of a recursive algorithm that will compute your power, without actually raising the number to more than an exponent of `2` (hence squaring).

The Java `BigInteger` class does, however, deal with the problem of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Wait ... if m is simply the length of S, it's all a lot simpler:

```
int re = 1;
int sig = 0;
for (int i=m-1; i>=0; --m) {
    if (s[i] != 0)
        sig ^= re;
    re = (re*r) & 0xffffffff;
}
```

This seems almost too simple to me; are you sure you have the expression correct?

(My original answer:

Start with an integer exponent function if you don't already have one:

```
/**
 * Return x^e, mod 2^32
 */
unsigned int
iExp(unsigned int x, unsigned int e)
{
    unsigned int rval = 1;
    while (e > 0) {
        if ((e & 1) != 0)
            rval *= x;
        x *= x;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return rval & 0xffffffff;
}
```

If S is an array of 0 or 1 values, then it's really a "use"/"don't use" flag for the rest of the subexpression:

```
// I've taken the liberty of indexing S starting at 0 instead of 1
// compute f(s) = (S[0]r^m-1) xor (S[1]r^m-2) xor....(xor S[m-1]r^0)) mod (2^32)

int rval = 0;
for (x : S) {
    --m;
    if (x != 0)
        rval ^= iExpr(r, m);
}
```

I haven't tested this (I don't have any test vectors), but this should do it.