# LongStream Java rangeClosed reduce - How to avoid a negative return?

Tags: java-8, stack-overflow, factorial

When n is equal to 50 this function returns a negative number, is there a substitute for LongStream like a "BigIntegerStream" that allows 'n' larger?

```
public static long factorial(int n) {

    if (n > 50 || n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(n + " is out of range");

    return LongStream.rangeClosed(2, n).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);

}
```

Comment: Yes. `Stream<BigInteger>`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a bigger primitive capacity, instead, you may want to use a `Stream<BigInteger>` like said by @Tunaki but keep the original `IntStream`.

The following code works perfectly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(factorial(10)); // 3 628 800 => CORRECT
}

public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
                    .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
                    .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, (a, b) -> a.multiply(b));
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and go for your method, but a have an ubderlying issue, the solution I crafted turns out to assigning high values to array indexes which has a constraint limit size: Integer.MAX_VALUE
Problems arise when the factorial input get higher then 20 and my code needs to support even a factorial(5,000) - five thousand... I think I get f*ck*d up with this algorithm of mine...

[Heap Challenge] (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-average-waiting-time/submissions/code/24209486)

Comment: @KRonaldoK It is very difficult to support factorial 5000 since you have memory limits while using BigInteger (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163434/does-biginteger-ever-overflows)